# Label wont change text

Tags: c#, while-loop, label

I am trying to put a label under my progress bar that changes according to the percentage of what has been finished. The math works, and the code looks like it should work but the label doesnt change while I am running the program. Here is a simple version of my code:

```
 while(...)
 {
     fileCount = fileCount + 1;
     progressBar1.Increment(1);
     changeText(sender, e, fileCount, progressBarCount);
 }


private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e, double fileCount, double progressBarCount)
{
    int percentage = Convert.ToInt32((fileCount / progressBarCount) * 100);
    Label percentageText = new Label();
    percentageText.Text = string.Format("{0}%", percentage);
}
```

Comment: Don't block the UI thread.

Comment: how would I do that? Can I get an example pls

Comment: Liberally sprinkle some `Application.DoEvents();` calls throughout your code (quick hack, UI still won't be smooth). Or look up `BackgroundWorker` and use it to do your work on a non-UI thread (proper solution).

Comment: @Secretario Financiero You are creating new label every time but not attach this label to UI. you should use label object that is already initialize in UI. show your UI code where you define label

Answer (score 0):

First add your control to your form:

`this.Controls.Add(percentageText);`

and then try calling the refresh method of your form using:

`this.Refresh();`

in your changeText() method.